# Setting maintenance policy for kubernetes cluster with frequency weekly and byday does not seem to work

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform

```
maintenance_policy {
  recurring_window {
    start_time = "2019-01-01T09:00:00-04:00"
    end_time = "2019-01-01T17:00:00-04:00"
    recurrence = "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA"
  }
}
```

> googleapi: Error 400: Error validating maintenance policy: maintenance policy would go longer than 14d without 24h maintenance availability of >= 4h co

Where do 14 days come from? If BYDAY is removed then the maintenance window is fine. According to GCP you can set weekly frequency and by day on beta provider?

Answer (score 1):

To configure a maintenance exclusion, you have to allow at least 24 hours of maintenance availability in a 14-day rolling window [1]. The start and end time you set does not meet the requirements. I would suggest to allow either a longer maintenance window or a shorter exclusion period.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/maintenance-windows-and-exclusions#configuring_a_maintenance_exclusion